# PHP embedd a PDF in a browser window

Tags: php, html, pdf, download

This code opens a PDF in a blank browser window with no extra style.

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($complete_path).'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' .filesize($complete_path));

$success = readfile($complete_path);
```

But I want to apply more info and some styling too. So I tried this code :

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
echo '<head>';
    echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
    echo '<title>'.$file_name.'</title>';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/docs.css" />';
echo '</head>';

echo '<body >';

    echo'<div class="frame">';
        $success = readfile($complete_path);
    echo'</div>';    

echo '</body>';
```

Obviously this fails, it was a quick try. So how to embedd a PDF file in a styled browser page ? I do not want to download it on disk.

Comment: Edited my answer with the PHP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed you can use `<embed>` to display PDF without downloading it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Embeded PDF</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed src="MY_PDF_FILE.PDF" type="application/pdf" height="25%" width="25%">
   </body>             ▲
</html>
```

Now the PHP way :

```
<?php
$pdf = "MY_PDF_FILE.PDF";        ◄
echo <<<BLOCK
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Embeded PDF</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <embed src="$pdf" type="application/pdf" height="25%" width="25%">
     </body>        ▲
  </html>
BLOCK;
?>
```

Comment: Great that works. But still have a problem. When I set the width and height to 100%, but it only applies to the width. The height has some 100px only. How extend that ?

Comment: @Ben, I'm testint both values (width and height) and both look independent, I mean, I can change one or the other and the PDF resizes.

Comment: @Ben, with 500px = `<embed src="$pdf" type="application/pdf" height="500px" width="100%">`.

Comment: Bingo - that's it, simple, if one knows ... Last Question : Works `<embed>` only for HTML 5 ?

Comment: @Ben, yes, html5 only.